# Find latest entry of a duplicate row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a spreadsheet that tracks the status of documents. Every time a document is worked on, a new row is added with that day's date and the new document status. This way I can track the progress/life-cycle of each document.

I want to filter this sheet (or show the relevant data in another sheet) to show the latest version of every document, based on the latest date.

For example, Document X might appear three times (because it was worked on three times), but I only want to show it once in the spreadsheet - the entry with the latest date.

Do you guys have any idea how I would do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dates in Column A and document names in Column B:

```
=query(A:B,"select B, max(A) group by B")
```

Reference

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)